# Mapbox Terrain v2: how do I modify contour elevation range?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, unity3d-terrain

I'm using Mapbox Terrain vector tileset to show elevation contours on my map. But my region of interest is quite flat, so there aren't any visible contours in that area. (basically, I see contours all around my region, but not in the actual region I need the contours for.)

**How do I modify the *ele* field of the *contour* layer to change the contour density?** Thank you!

[Mapbox Terrain-v2, #contour, **ele** field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qzWm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, you have to use the [`exaggeration`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/terrain/) param, that will exaggerates the elevation of the terrain by multiplying the data from the DEM with this value

```js
map.setTerrain({ 
  'source': 'mapbox-dem', 
  'exaggeration': 1.5 // x1.5 multiplier to exaggerate DEM data
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually meant to ask about the mapbox **terrain-v2** (https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-terrain-v2/), not the 3D terrain elevation. I've put an image in my original post for clarification. Do you have a suggestion for how to edit the "ele" field?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question then